# Почему в режиме инкогнито страница отображается нормально. А в обычном режиме — нет?

Tags: wordpress

Я внес правки на сайт через плагин Elementor. Смотрю страницу в режиме инкогнито - она отображается корректно. Смотрю в обычном режиме - верстка едет.

Я понимаю, что проблема в кеше браузера. Но как ее решить?

Вот, что я пробовал.

1. Нашел и установил плагин "Busted!". Судя по описанию, он заставляет браузер скачивать файлы и кешировать заново, если они изменились. Но мне не помогло.
2. Сбросил кеш от плагина autoptimize - не помогло.
3. Сбросил кеш от плагина WP Super Cache - не помогло.
4. Нажал "Пересоздать CSS" в Elementor -> Инструменты - не помогло.
5. Добавил в шапку темы этот код:

   ```
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
   ```

Не помогло.

Что еще можно сделать?

Comment: Сделали кучу всякой ненужной дребедени, а забыли самое главное — сбросить кеш браузера.

Comment: @andreymal, я не могу заставить всех посетителей сайта нажать Ctrl+F5. Кто-то зайдет, увидит, что сайт корявый. И уйдет с него.

Comment: Значит вы уже опоздали, и единственный способ решить проблему — поменять все ссылки на закэшировавшиеся файлы

Comment: @andreymal , неужели в Wordpress все так плохо, что я не могу заставить браузер обновить кеш? Даже заголовками?

Comment: Это не зависит от вордпресса, это прописанное стандартом поведение HTTP: если сервер изначально разрешил положить в файл в кеш, то он так и будет в кеше, пока кто-нибудь не нажмёт Ctrl+F5 (ну или не изменит ссылку, по сути подсунув другой файл)

Comment: А можно как-нибудь в Wordpress быстренько добавить для всех скриптов и стилей (не только тех, что от темы, но и для тех, что от плагинов) версию (например: style.css?v=1)?